# How to loop around asynchronous functions in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

I am trying to get posts from database by using ID.So I am looping around an array of Id's and using mongoose method 'findById' to get response.But the loop finishes iterations before completing the body.
How to deal with this?

```
function getSortedPosts(callback){
    var landingPosts = new Object;
    categoryModel.find((err,categories) => {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        else{
            categories.forEach((category,i) => {
                landingPosts[category.category] = new Array;
                //for each post in  a category
                category.posts.forEach((postid,j) => {
                    console.log(":")
                    //limiting posts per category to 3
                    if (j<3){
                        postModel.findById(postid,(err,foundpost) => {
                            if(err) console.log(err)
                            else{
                                landingPosts[category.category].push(foundpost);
                                if(i === categories.length-1){
                                    console.log(i)
                                    if(j === 2){
                                      callback(landingPosts);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    })
}
getSortedPosts((lp) => {.......})
```

I don't know how to use promises or async await...so I am using callbacks.
Would learning them now help me with this?
(I plan to learn them after present project as I am beginner and they confuse me)

Comment: *"Would learning them now help me with this?"* Yes, but you'd need a wrapper for `findById`, which doesn't [seem to return a promise](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) (I find that odd, I thought they'd added promises to the API).

Comment: Is it: A) Important that the operations run in *series* (one after another); B) Important that they run in *parallel* (all at once, overlapping); or C) Either way is fine ?

Comment: [My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43766002/157247) shows how to do multiple async operations (with and without promises), but I hesitate to dupehammer this question as a duplicate of that one...though I suppose it is, really, by SO's definition.

Comment: I want them to run in series. A).

Comment: Side note about `var landingPosts = new Object;`: There's almost never any reason to use `new Object` instead of `{}`, like this: `var landingPosts = {};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely learn `async await` before even starting this project.

```
async function getSortedPosts() {
    var landingPosts = {};
    var categories = await categoryModel.find().catch(console.log);
    for(let item of categories) {
        let category = item.category;
        landingPosts[category] = [];

        for(let id of item.posts.slice(0,2)) {
            let post = await postModel.findById(id).catch(console.log);
            landingPosts[category].push(post);
        }
    }

    return landingPosts;
}
```

Call the `getSortedPosts` function like this -

```
getSortedPosts().then(landingPosts => {
    // some logic
})
```

I didn't run the code, but hope you can solve the errors.

Answer (score 1):

I would divide the functionalities in different functions which does only one job and then have another one which uses these function to get the final output. something like this

```
function findPostById(postId) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    postModel.findById(postid, (err, foundpost) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(foundpost);
      }
    });
  });
}

function findCategories() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    categoryModel.find((err, categories) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve(categories);
    });
  });
}

async function getSortedPosts() {
  const categories = await findCategories();
  const landingPosts = {};
  for (const category of categories) {
    for (const post of category.posts) {
      const foundpost = await findById(post.postId);
      landingPosts[category.category].push(foundpost);
    }
  }
}
```

I haven't done the logic for limiting the number of posts but you get an idea, how to structure the code.

Hope this helps